# I am unable to download an audio book that I bought from iTunes to my iPhone 5

Tags: iphone, itunes, ibook

I am unable to download an audio book that I bought from iTunes to my iPhone 5. It appears on my phone only in the shared folder when I'm connected to iTunes. When I exit iTunes the book disappears.

Comment: Do you get notification? What iPhone are you using, what iTunes are you using? What iOS do you run, and what platform do you run iTunes on? Please add more details, such as these above.

Comment: Are you looking for it in the Music app?  That is where audiobooks appear.

Answer (score 1):

I think audiobooks get somehow special treatment, so that can not be re-downloaded them (even if accidentally deleted).
You have to copy it from iTunes over to your iPhone.